# What are the most historically relevant implementations of Prolog? And what platforms?

Tags: history, programming

Does anyone know what are the most historically relevant implementations of Prolog, in the sense of being extensively used, and producing representative programs written in this language? And what computer platforms were notoriously associated with them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#History Mentions a few influential versions; the first ever, the first with modern syntax, the first with a compiler.

Comment: Are *any* implementations of Prolog historically relevant?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, usually any answer to a question with so many opinion based criteria would be *at least* debatable, if not total off topic. But in case of Prolog there is in fact a clear answer (*1):

**Turbo Prolog for MS-DOS**

Today's incarnation is known as [Visual Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Prolog) (*2).

It became an instant success when [published first in 1986](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=SS8EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&source=bl&ots=swrXBFsXJo&sig=ACfU3U0LL_vsRZyFEQjHEdPBY8ydfU6Wfw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKyvr9x738AhW5QvEDHQghDoUQ6AF6BAgzEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false). At a price of only USD 99.95 it sold in numbers unheard of for such an exotic language, instantly becoming the most used as well as most influential due to reaching the most people ever. No other Prolog implementation did ever reach as many people or attention from non-scholar circles. It pushed the use of Prolog in many projects outside schools and universities.

Even today [it's used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zf9ucGi5yug) in some places to give a first impression to students.

---

*1 - That is unless the parameters get tweaked to be even more fuzzy :)

*2 - One could as well say 'again known' as the company behind Visual Prolog is PDC, a Danish company, which developed the original Turbo Prolog as PDC Prolog. Borland 'only' licensed it.